# How to create a "poll" in Microsoft Outlook 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2011

Is it possible to create a vote/poll in a message in Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac OS X?

[image]

Here's an [example of how it could be done](http://lis.dickinson.edu/technology/training/Tutorials/2010/outlook/vote.pdf) in Windows version of Outlook.

Comment: What???????????

Comment: See example how it could be done in windows version of outlook, so you are basically add voting options to your email. http://lis.dickinson.edu/technology/training/Tutorials/2010/outlook/vote.pdf

Comment: It's possible that it just doesn't work in the mac version. Most people agree that the mac version lacks **many** options from the windows version. But perhaps this help?s [Create polls in email messages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-polls-in-e-mail-messages-and-review-the-results-HP010080425.aspx)

Comment: yes, well, but it seems that mac os version has no such options and buttons((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this is not an option at this time.